# How to send DELETE request in jQuery/JS when the library itself uses POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-file-input

I'm using Kartik-v/file-input or known as Boostrap File Input, and want to delete uploaded images.

From the [docs](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-options#initialPreviewConfig), I've provided the delete URLs for the images stored on the server. Which these delete URLs are API, and accepting DELETE request. However, the `url` is sending POST request, which then my Laravel throws an exception that says:

`The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.`.

How can I work around on this? How can I make the `url:` will send DELETE request instead of POST?

```js
$('.uploaded-images').fileinput({
        browseLabel: 'Browse',
        browseIcon: '<i class="icon-file-plus mr-2"></i>',
        uploadIcon: '<i class="icon-file-upload2 mr-2"></i>',
        initialPreview: [
            'image/an-example-image.png',
            'image/an-example-image2.png',
        ],
        initialPreviewConfig: [
            {caption: 'Jane.jpg', key: 1, url: 'http://web.com/api/medias/14', showDrag: false},
            {caption: 'Anna.jpg', key: 2, url: '{$url}', showDrag: false}
        ],
        initialPreviewAsData: true,
        overwriteInitial: false,
        maxFileSize: 1000,
    });
```

Comment: the methods names are case sensitive so ```Route::get('/foo',  'FooController@method')->name('foo.method');```  but    ```Route::**GET**('/foo',  'FooController@method')->name('foo.method');``` won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the [source](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/blob/master/js/fileinput.js#L3625) of the library and its [docs](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-options#ajaxDeleteSettings). You can supply the request method as jquery ajax option to its option: `ajaxDeleteSettings`. Example

```
$('.uploaded-images').fileinput({
    browseLabel: 'Browse',
    browseIcon: '<i class="icon-file-plus mr-2"></i>',
    uploadIcon: '<i class="icon-file-upload2 mr-2"></i>',
    initialPreview: [
        'image/an-example-image.png',
        'image/an-example-image2.png',
    ],
    initialPreviewConfig: [
        {caption: 'Jane.jpg', key: 1, url: 'http://web.com/api/medias/14', showDrag: false},
        {caption: 'Anna.jpg', key: 2, url: '{$url}', showDrag: false}
    ],
    initialPreviewAsData: true,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    maxFileSize: 1000,
    ajaxDeleteSettings: {
        type: 'DELETE' // This should override the ajax as $.ajax({ type: 'DELETE' })
    }
});
```

You can also define the option globally somewhere before defining above snippet.

```
$.fn.fileinput.defaults.ajaxDeleteSettings = {
    type: 'DELETE'
};
```

Comment: Thank You @Chay22, I didn't know that I can override the Delete Method of this plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try including the below hidden input field in your form, and send the request, while your form's submit type is **POST**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work as when the image is deleted, ithe request sent via Ajax.

Comment: Have you still got the same error while you send the form data with that hidden input field?

Comment: Yes, the same error. I'm using that kartik-v/file-input plugin and it provide delete button, which if you click it, it will use the value on `url` with POST request, while my API is accepting DELETE request

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your Ajax request headers? I wanna see how your form data are sending over the request.

Answer (score 0):

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

Laravel needs extra info added to their forms to properly send DELETE requests.

If you're using Blade templates, then it would look something like:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'delete', 'class' => 'deleteForm']) }}
  <input type="submit" class="deleteBtn" />
{{ Form::close() }}
```

If you're not using Blade templates, then add one of the following right after declaring your form (in HTML):

```
{{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
```

or

```
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
```

You can look more into DELETE requests in laravel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879645/laravel-delete-forms), and [here](http://www.rappasoft.com/articles/trigger-delete-requests-with-a-link-in-laravel-5/)

I also saw your comment mentioning that:

> I'm using that kartik-v/file-input plugin and it provide delete button

I've never used the plugin before; but maybe you can edit/modify the button to properly send the DELETE request by encapsulating the button in a form?

For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/users/{{$user->id}}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

        <-- Your Delete Button/Input field Here -->
</form>
```

Comment: "maybe you can edit/modify the button to properly send the DELETE request by encapsulating the button in a form?" - this one I don't know how to do this

Comment: @PramanaAdiPutra Hi, I've edited my answer with an example to answer your question.